# why does not std:cin recognise enter key

Tags: c++, user-input

I am trying to take input from command prompt and put every input separated by white-space or tab to vector  until user presses "enter". I am not able to do do. here is my code

```
template <typename T> 
vector <T> process_input_stream() {

    T value;
    vector <T> vect;

    string line;
    //read input and populate into vect until return key is pressed
    while (getline(cin, line, '\n')){
        cin >> value;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        vect.push_back(value);
    }

    return vect;
}
```

now the problem i am hitting my head to, is, when entering input, input is screen is still asking for more input even after pressing enter key.

Comment: What do you think `while(getline(...))` does?

Comment: (and you're ignoring the actually extracted `line`). So you need an `if` (not really, the `line` will be empty after a failure) and a `std::istringstream`.

Answer (score 3):

The `line` variable contains the whole line, except the linefeed.

To parse each line, you could replace your `while` loop with:

```
while (getline(cin, line))
{
    istringstream iss(line);
    while (iss >> value)
    {
        vect.push_back(value);
    }
}
```